# How do I get the current Project Template Name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I have DTE.Project object - How do I get from there the Project Template Name?

I'm trying to detect the project template so I would be able to later on recreate it programmatically. if I have the name i can do it. Is that the right way to go?

I've already seen http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/mz2007016.aspx, but not all projects have "projectTypeGuids", for example, Windows Forms Application and Console Application, and ProjectType and OutputType properties doesn't help me because they are the same for the aforementioned templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer could be found here: (it's hebrew)

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shlomo/archive/2012/10/10/how-do-i-get-the-current-project-template.aspx